# Random name selector using a picker view with swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm trying populate a pickerview using the text from labels.
I've tried searching online and in books for how to do this but no luck yet.
what i have so far shows no errors but still won't run

thanks

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate{

```
@IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var textField3: UITextField!


@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {

    label.text = textField.text
    label2.text = textField2.text
    label3.text = textField3.text
    self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
    self.textField2.resignFirstResponder()
    self.textField3.resignFirstResponder()
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return false
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}


var pickerLabels: [UILabel!] {

    return [label,label2,label3]
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
     return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component:Int) -> Int{
    return pickerLabels.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSArray{

return pickerLabels

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}
```

}

Comment: Edit your question and: Change the wall of text to separate paragraphs with reasonable punctuation and grammar.  Show the code you have so far.  Don't need smiley face.  Note that it is common to use an array with picker views but not required.  But imagine: What if pressing the button updates an array with the text from the text fields and then tells the picker view to reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `UILabels` to your array.
I believe what you are trying to achieve needs you to get the text from the `UILabels` and also to format the array as `[String]` on your computed property..

```
var pickerLabels: [String!] {

    return [label.text, label2.text, label3.text]
}
```